# How to deal with onLoad and onClick events in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mouseevent, dom-events

I'm trying to convert an app that did not use node.js to node format.

The initial app consisted of just a `code.js` file and the `index.html` file which was like this :

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
     (...)
    <div style="position:absolute; top:250px; left:20px">
      <input type="button" onClick="init()" value="New game">
     (...)
</body>
</html>
```

To convert this to node format, I renamed `index.html` as `views/index.ejs`, and replaced the js functions with ejs quotes :

```
<html>
...
<body onload="<%= load %>()">
     (...)
    <div style="position:absolute; top:250px; left:20px">
      <input type="button" onClick="<%=init %>()" value="New game">
     (...)
</body>
</html>
```

I also added the following at the end of my code.js file :

```
module.exports={
  load:load,
  init:init
}
```

And finally, in my `app.js` main node file I have the following relevant snippet :

```
var exportedValues = require('./code.js');
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
   res.render('index.ejs',exportedValues);
});
```

This almost works : when I inspect  the console, the ejs quotes are indeed replaced with the definitions of the `load` and `init` functions, but as those definitions, in turn, use other functions defined in `code.js`, the browser does not know what to do with them.

What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by converting it to "node format"... Node is JavaScript running on the server... HTML (the JS in it) runs in the browser. You cannot run Node code in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to the code loaded in the html; none of that ejs syntax is necessary. Once you have the html/ejs being sent to the client, it will request the js resource (code.js) as normal. If you want some code to run on the server in response to some action by the client, then you can send a request to the server, with optional parameters, and have the server return a response after doing some work.

You may look at these resources to learn about communicating between client and server:

- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)
- [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/)